# Inverting the data structure using backbone relational

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, data-structures, backbone-relational

I'm using backbone-relational to write an app using nested data. The top level of the data structure contains most of the data (in terms of MB) but is never used as a standalone item; it's only used to flesh out the attributes of its related children (flyweight pattern?).

To send all this data to the browser I'm using something like the following data structure

```
records = [ 
   {performerName: 'Jane', details: {composerName: 'Beethoven', ... }}, 
   ... 
]
```

And this is then encapsulated by two models, `Piece` and `Performance` - both inherit from Backbone.RelationalModel but only `Performance` has a relation defined as follows

```
relations: [
    {
        type: 'HasOne',
        key: 'piece',
        relatedModel: 'Piece',
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'performances'
        }
    }
],
```

and then a performances collection can be built straight from the original JSON.

This all works fine, but the problem is that I'm sending several copies of the data for each `Piece` (as each piece typically has several performances) so the download size is a lot bigger than it needs to be.

What's the best way to send a lighter weight data structure ( as below or some other structure that avoids masses of duplication) and yet still have relatively painless creation of the performances collection I need to work with.

```
records = [ 
   {composerName: 'Beethoven', ..., performances: [array of jsons, one for each performance] 
   ... 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this in the end was to send the data as

```
var data = { pieces: [
              {tune_name: 'eidelweiss', ..., performances: [{id:23}, {id:52}]} 
              ... 
             ],
             performances: [ array of performance jsons ]
           };
```

In the pieces model define the following relation

```
relations: [
    {
        type: 'HasMany',
        key: 'performances',
        relatedModel: 'Performance',
    includeInJSON: false,
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'piece'
        }
    }
]
```

and then just build a performances collection and a pieces collection as normal